# Angular 6 - Error login to return http status 403

Tags: angular, cors, http-status-code-403

I have based on the following link to practice with a login in Angular:
https://medium.com/@ozgurgul/angular-6-login-and-router-tutorial-ac5fc5d3027f

I need to test the application locally, I have configured a proxy.conf.json file for the Angular App to avoid problems with CORS (proxy.conf.json):

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8002/login",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

When I try to perform the login I get the following error:

```
Http 403 (forbidden)
```

This is my angular component (login.component.ts)

```
 tryLogin(email: string, password: string) {
    this.loginService.login(
      email,
      password
    ).subscribe(
      r => {
        if (r.token) {
          this.customerService.setToken(r.token);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
        }
      },
      r => {
        alert(r.error.status); //here I get the error 403
    });
 }
```

And this is my angular service (login.service.ts)

```
apiPath: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiPath = '/api';
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<LoginResultModel> {
    return this.http.post<LoginResultModel>(this.apiPath, {
      email: email,
      password: password
    });
  }
```

What could be the problem? thanks,

Comment: Might be a permission problem. Try `sudo chmod -R 777 <path-to-folder>` where <path-to-folder> is the path of the server side of your app where the login autentication is performed

Comment: The OS is windows, do not know if the problem is in Angular or in Java?

Comment: Windows is also using permissions for its filesystem. I hesitate that the problem resides in angular since more likely a server side problem. Usually this problem comes after a bad folder permissions configuration, but something else could be causing this